# Javascript flatmap understanding?

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I'm not familiar with Javascript, but trying to essentially flatmap the following:

The spot where I see     `(5) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]` I want to appear like the others where they're all separated.

```
0
:
(5) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
1
:
(2) [-112.2550785337791, 36.07954952145647]
2
:
(2) [-112.2549277039738, 36.08117083492122]
3
:
(2) [-112.2552505069063, 36.08260761307279]
4
:
(2) [-112.2564540158376, 36.08395660588506]
5
:
(2) [-112.2580238976449, 36.08511401044813]
6
:
(2) [-112.2595218489022, 36.08584355239394]
7
:
(2) [-112.2608216347552, 36.08612634548589]
8
:
(2) [-112.262073428656, 36.08626019085147]
9
:
(2) [-112.2633204928495, 36.08621519860091]
10
:
(2) [-112.2644963846444, 36.08627897945274]
11
:
(2) [-112.2656969554589, 36.08649599090644]
```

I have the following code:

```
let parsedGeoCoords = _.flatten(aoiList.map((aoi) => {
  return terraformer.parse(aoi.geo).coordinates
}), true)
```

### New Attempt? Messy

```
let data = [
  [["1", "3"],["2", "5"],["3", "7"]],
  ["4", "5"],
  ["5", "56"]
]
function flatten(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function (flat, toFlatten) {
    return flat.concat(is2DArray(toFlatten) ? (toFlatten) : [(toFlatten)]);
  }, []);
}

function is2DArray(arr) {
  return Array.isArray(arr[0])
}

console.log(flatten(data))
```

## Input Data

```
let data = [
  [["1", "3"],["2",3],["3","5"]],
  ["4", "5"],
  ["5", "56"],
  "4",
  "7"
]
```

## Desire

```
[ [ '1', '3' ],
  [ '2', 3 ],
  [ '3', '5' ],
  [ '4', '5' ],
  [ '5', '56' ],
  [ '4', '7' ] ]
```

Comment: Exactly what do you want? and what's not happening?

Comment: I want the 2d arrays to be flattened

Comment: You seem to be looking at output in the console. If so, you can click on those `Array(2)` and see more detail. If you need specific output, then please show the code with which you produce the output - how you convert it to a string - and how that differs from what you really want.

Comment: maybe you want to see it with? `JSON.stringify(yourArray)` or  `[].concat.apply([], yourArray)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just fix the current output to match what you want. Just add:

```
var fullFlatten = _.flatten(_.map(data, function(elem) {
   return _.flatten(elem);
}));
var chunks = _.chunk(fullFlatten, 2);
```

Comment: The order could be totally random where the 2d array is

Comment: _ is lodash or underscore? Or another library?

Comment: underscore in my case

Comment: my favourite array/object manipulation javascript library to date :) I've edited my answer above for a random item like  [["1", "3"],["2", "5"],["3", "7"]] in the full array.

Comment: I've updated input and desired output, can it support that?

Comment: Then it seems simpler to flatten the array completely and then split in pairs of 2 elems, would it be good?

Comment: Check the current, edited answer for this version, it returns the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

With lodash you can simply use [flattenDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#flattenDeep) and then [chunk](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#chunk):

```js
let data = [  [["1", "3"],["2",3],["3","5"]],  ["4", "5"],  ["5", "56"],  "4",  "7"]

console.log(_.chunk(_.flattenDeep(data), 2)) // with no chaining

// with chaining
console.log( 
   _(data)
   .flattenDeep()
   .chunk(2)
   .value()
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```